# Синхронизация базы данных андроид приложения с базой данных сервера

Tags: java, android, sql-server, sqlite, wcf

Есть андроид приложение с базой данных (sqlite) и база данных на сервере предприятия (ms sql). Пользователь работает с приложение и заполняет/обновляет данные на нём, из-за чего данные в базе приложения и базе на сервере не соответствуют. Необходимо реализовать синхронизацию данных в базах, но я   новичок в этом, и не знаю с чего начать. Приложение для андроид написано на java. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать, или где прочитать про подобное, может есть какие-то книги, статьи. Обратил внимание на WCF.

Comment: я не знаю ответа на ваш вопрос, но если бы я делал синхронизацию, я бы выбрал таблицу, которую буду синхронизировать, сдела бы там основным ключем GUID, записывал бы туда дату последнего изменения для каждой строчки, и в итоге этой информации бы хватило для синхронизации конкретной таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

Универсального ответа нет. Зависит того как используется база. Из вариантов:

1. У каждой записи есть метка времени последнего изменения. Unixtime вполне сойдет. Это поле ставит только сервер. Когда вы создаете на телефоне новую запись или редактируете пришедшую с сервера - ставите в метку 0. При синхронизации телефон отправляет на сервер список записей, у которых время 0(все измененные и созданные данные) и время последней синхронизации(0 по умолчанию). Сервер кушает данные, записывает изменения, и отдает текущее свое время(которое сохраняется на телефоне как время последней синхронизации) и все данные, время изменения которых больше присланного телефоном времени последней синхронизации.
2. Почти тоже самое, но вместо времени используем номер операции. Каждая синхронизация сервера с каким-либо клиентом увеличивает номер операции на 1, и у всех данных, которые прислал клиент в ходе синхронизации, указан этот номер операции. Отдаем клиенту все данные с номером выше, чем самый большой имеющийся на клиенте.

Минусы обоих подходов - одна синхронизация - одна транзакция, пусть даже очень большая, ибо если на сервер одну и ту же строку пришлют почти одновременно с разным содержимым можем получить несогласованные данные, и удаление строк невозможно. Если удалить строку на сервере клиент никогда не получит инфу о том, что она удалена. Нужно делать флаг удаленной строки и хранить на клиенте все эти мертвые данные, если не изобретать что-то посложнее

3. Версионный. Действуем аки VCS - позволяем делать в базе клиента все, что он захочет, раз в N времени всю клиентскую базу шлем на сервер. Там она либо становится новой актуальной базой, либо выдает конфликтные места, если кто-то правил в базе что-то что и мы. Если редкие синхронизации допустимы - пожалуй лучший вариант.

Есть еще пара подходов с более гибкой, но куда более сложно реализованной синхронизацией. Но тут только с хороши знанием предметной области можно дать дельный совет